# C# winforms:Microsoft Report viewer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset, reportviewer

I want to search person by auto increment ID `(textbox and one button)`. I have used `dataset` and in that

`Fill,Getdata --> configure`

SQL statement :

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, ContactNo, Address, Date, NameOfJob, OtherJob,
Impression, BackPage, NameOfPage, PaperSize, PrintingSize,
DesignRupees, JobRupees, Matter, BlackPlate, BlackPlateRupees, SinglePlate, 
SinglePlateRupees, MultiPlate, MultiPlateRupees, Platename, 
Lamination, Creasing, Binding, Other, Total, Receive, Due, LastRemaining
FROM bill WHERE  ID=@ID
```

after that I have run the program then  2 error shows:

1. cannot convert from string to decimal
2. The best overloaded method match for `WindowsFormsApplication9.DataSet1TableAdapters.billTableAdapter.Fill(WindowsFormsApplication9.DataSet1.billDataTable, decimal) has some invalid arguments` error in this line

   `this.billTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.bill, txt_search.Text);`

Comment: The error message "cannot convert from string to decimal" is pretty clear.  You are sending a string when it expects a decimal.

Comment: now i have done everything after that one new problem generated ...now error not shown but when i search by ID then constraint exception generated : failed to enable constraints one or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your errors are:

`cannot convert from string to decimal`

and

`WindowsFormsApplication9.DataSet1TableAdapters.billTableAdapter.Fill(WindowsFormsApplication9.DataSet1.billDataTable, decimal);`

if you look at what you are trying to put into the `Fill()` method:

`this.billTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.bill, txt_search.Text);`

What your errors are telling you is that it can't convert a string into a decimal. Your fill method is requiring a decimal as it's second parameter, but you are providing it a string (`txt_search.Text`).

You need to Convert/Parse the string into a decimal first, then call your `.Fill()` method with this value.

Have a look into [`decimal.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) and [`decimal.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557).

Comment: now error not shown but when i search by ID then constraint exception generated : failed to enable constraints one or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Comment: ITS: That's an SQL error. You should look at your tables, foreign-keys and other constraints to attempt to determine the issue. If you have no luck, then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument should be `decimal` but you are passing `string` value that is `txt_search.Text`.

So you can cast that to decimal as:

```
this.billTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.bill, (decimal)txt_search.Text);
```

or

```
this.billTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.bill, decimal.Parse(txt_search.Text));
```

Comment: now error not shown but when i search by ID then constraint exception generated : failed to enable constraints one or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Comment: There may be a chance that some foreign-key violation is there..try to debug the code and check the values in `Dataset1`.@ITS

Comment: what was the issue..?and why you accepted that answer..? @ITS